# Oracle update where select statement returns multiple row error

Tags: database, oracle, select, where-clause

Hi i have a table like this:

ID  Name  Number

1   john  91234567

2   tom   98765432

3   ken   91357246
...

I am trying to change number [91234567] to another number but i get this single row query returns more than 1 row.

My statement:

```
Update table set number = '9000000' where id = (select id from table where number = '91234567')
```

Perhaps i have another record with the same number further down the table.

Since i do not have access to the id, how can i change my statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `IN` instead of `=`

```
Update table 
set number = '9000000' 
where id IN (select id from table where number = '91234567')
```

Comment: Thanks.. works beautifully.. will green tick in a moment

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change all the records containing 91234567 to 9000000:

```
update table
set number = 9000000
where number = 91234567
```

Comment: Sorry but i need to update using the primary key id.. sorry for not stating clearly

Comment: Then simply use `ID IN (...` instead of  `ID = (`